# How to calculate the expectation of a sequence of bets?

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose that the probability of losing a dollar is $2/3$ and winning is $1/3$. 
If I  start with $X$ dollars, what is the probability that I come out with $Y$ dollars?
I assume that I go home if I lose all the money or I get $Y$ dollars.

Comment: It's a standard problem - a straight Bernoulli random walk starting from $x$, with two absorbing barriers at $0$ and $y$ respectively. See the slides in the section labelled "Classical ruin problem" [here](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xbouda1/teaching/2009/IV111/lecture4.pdf)

Comment: thnk u so much Glen :)